# List of nodes limited by last node created from each user

Tags: 7, views, users

I am using Drupal 7, and I want to create a views which lists all the nodes that match the following criteria:

- Only the nodes whose content type is A, B, C
- The latest nodes of those content types created by all the users, one node for each user

How do I create it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily with views; it would be much cleaner to do from a custom module, especially as your final output seems to be a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Views 3 has the perfect new relationship type for this "Obtains a single representative node for each user, according to a chosen sort criterion."

To do this, begin with a new view which is a list of Users in fields format. By default you will see a list of usernames.

Then add a relationship 'User: Representative node (search for 'represent' when adding the relationship. You can choose the sort criteria as perhaps 'updated date' order by descending.

You can now add extra fields using the related data - such as 'Content: title' and 'Content: Updated date' using the relationship 'representative node' for each new field.

Comment: Sorting is not working for me, i created a representative node for some taxonomy term, i tried to sort it by flag counter, but i didn't find anything related to flag, then i tried sorting by content: update date , which is also not working for me.

Comment: To see the flag related sorting terms, you may need to add a relationship to the flag.  To expose the flag count, you'll need to do this in the outer (user related) query.

This sounds like this deserves a separate question to address it properly, as someone might be able to help you find a less complex way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

another approach is by creating two views:

1-a view that return a the latest post for the content types(A,B,C) for a specific user by accepting the uid as an argument.

2-the second view return a list of the users.

the trick here is to use the module [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view), and add "view field" to the second view then insert the first view with uid as an argument in it.

i hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using Views3.

1. First create a `users view`. You can do this by selecting 'Show Users' on the page `admin/structure/views/add`
2. Add a new relation-ship of type `User: Representative node` As the description reads it *Obtains a single representative node for each user, according to a chosen sort criterion.*
3. In the Relationship settings page select `Representative sort criteria` as `Content : Post Date` and check `Requires this relationship`, If you want to list only users with some content.
4. Goto Filters add a new filter `Content: Type`. Select the content types A,B and C
5. Goto fields and add any fields you want from the Representative node.